# Loop over df file field and store as txt

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a df with usernames like this

```
user                  pass
name1.last@gmail.com  123 
name2.last@gmail.com  456 
name3.last@gmail.com  789
```

I would like to be able to go over the list and store a txt file like this

```
TXT File:
- user: name1.last@gmail.com
  pass: 123
- user: name2.last@gmail.com
  pass: 456
- user: name1.last@gmail.com
  pass: 789
```

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `paste` the columns and write to a file with `cat`

```
str1 <-  with(df1, paste('TXT File:\n', 
     paste('- user:', user, '\n', ' pass:', pass, collapse='\n')))


cat(str1, 'file.txt')
```

print to console

```
cat(str1, '\n')
TXT File:
 - user: name1.last@gmail.com 
  pass: 123
- user: name2.last@gmail.com 
  pass: 456
- user: name3.last@gmail.com 
  pass: 789
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(user = c("name1.last@gmail.com", "name2.last@gmail.com", 
"name3.last@gmail.com"), pass = c(123L, 456L, 789L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```